# Python/Kivy : Call function from one class to another class in python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy`.I have a file `test.py`.
Can someone tell me how to call `def abc(self):` from `def update(self):` ?
Now i am using `Invoice().abc()` for call then it prints `calling` but not showing `label` and `value`

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from functools import partial
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (600, 600)

class MyLabel(Label):
    pass

class check(Popup):
    mode = StringProperty("")
    col_data = ListProperty(["?"])

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(check, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        if obj.mode == "Update":
            cur.execute("select `column` from `table_name` where `id`=?",(edit_id,))
            row = cur.fetchone()
            self.col_data[1] = row[0]

    def update(self):
        #do some stuff after call abc function
        Invoice().abc()

class Invoice(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Invoice, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def abc(self):
        print('calling')
        #fetching from database
        arr = [(11, 'Item1', '1001'), (12, 'Item2', '2001'), (13, 'Item3', '102')]
        layout = self.ids['invoices']
        for row in arr:
            layout.add_widget(MyLabel(text=str('[ref=world]' + row[1]) + '[/ref]',
                                      size_hint_x=.35,
                                      halign='left',
                                      markup=True,
                                      on_ref_press=partial(self.open_form, row[0])))

    def open_form(self, id, *args):
        global edit_id
        edit_id = id
        self.mode = "Update"
        check(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never running the `build` function in `Test` to create the instance of `Invoice`. Try this code out for your main function. The first line sets `x` equal to the data returned by `Test().build()` which is `Invoice()` thus giving x the properties of `Invoice` Class.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=Test().build()
    x.abc()
```

The next bit will answer the question how to I call `abc()` from a different class.  You can change your `update` function to this:

```
def update(self):
        #do some stuff after call abc function
        x=Invoice()
        x.abc()
```

You first need to construct the class by `x=Invoice()` then you can call the functions inside of `Invoice` with with this format `x.abc()`

Comment: sorry for inconvenience.I have updated code.`Invoice()` function not in `def build(self):`.

Comment: I am updating this answer to help with the main question now. Just saw I missed the question.

Comment: @macsontaylor did that help out? If so feel free to accept and upvote!

Comment: thanks.It prints `arr` data but not working layout.add_widget when call from another class.If i call `on_press:root.abc()` from .kv file then it's working.i don't know what is wrong?

Comment: My example like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334295/python-kivy-call-function-from-one-class-to-another-class-and-show-widget-iin