# Python/Kivy : Call function from one class to another class and show widget in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am using Python-2.7 and Kivy. When I run **test.py** then a show button shows. When I click on the show button then a label and value shows. I am fetching it from the database but now I defined it as a static array.

When I click on Item1 label then call def open_form and pass id 11 after calling `EditPopup(self)` with id and show a popup with value.

After that I change `itemCode` and click on the ok button then it updates data in the database.

After that I call `Invoice().abc()` then it prints the updated data in `Pycharm` console but not showing latest the data in `layout.add_widget`(Popup window).

Can someone tell me where am I making a mistake?

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from functools import partial
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
import sqlite3 as lite
#con = lite.connect('test.db')

#con.text_factory = str
#cur = con.cursor()
Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (600, 600)

class MyLabel(Label):
    pass


class EditPopup(Popup):
    mode = StringProperty("")
    label_rec_id = StringProperty("Id")
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?"])
    index = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(EditPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        if obj.mode == "Update":
            #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE itemId=?", (edit_id,))
            #row = cur.fetchone()
            row = (11, 'Item1', '1001')
            print(row[0])
            self.col_data[0] = str(row[0])
            self.col_data[1] = row[1]
            self.col_data[2] = row[2]

    def update(self,obj):
        #cur.execute("UPDATE `item` SET itemName=?, itemCode=? WHERE itemId=?",
                #('Item1', 9999, 11))
        #con.commit()
        Invoice().abc()

class Invoice(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Invoice, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def abc(self):
        #fetching from database
        #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `item` order by itemId asc")
        #rows = cur.fetchall()
        rows = [(11, 'Item1', '1001'), (12, 'Item2', '2001'), (13, 'Item3', '102')]
        print(rows)
        layout = self.ids['invoices']
        for row in rows:
            layout.add_widget(MyLabel(text=str('[ref=world]' + row[1]) + '[/ref]',
                                      size_hint_x=.35,
                                      halign='left',
                                      markup=True,
                                      on_ref_press=partial(self.open_form, row[0])))

    def open_form(self, id, *args):
        global edit_id
        edit_id = id
        self.mode = "Update"
        popup = EditPopup(self)
        popup.open()

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return Invoice()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    size_hint_y:None
    height: 30

<MyLabel>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    size_hint_y:None
    height: 30
    text_size: self.size
    valign: 'middle'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .6, .6, .6
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<EditPopup>:
    title: self.mode + " Item"
    size_hint: None, None
    title_size: 20
    title_font: "Verdana"
    size: 400, 275
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            #backgroun_color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
            spacing: 10, 10
            padding: 20, 20
            Label:
                text: root.label_rec_id
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                id: itemId
                text: root.col_data[0]
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text: "Item Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                id: itemName
                text: root.col_data[1]
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text: "State Code"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                id: itemCode
                text: root.col_data[2]
                text_size: self.size

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 10, 0, 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: .55, .3
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.65}

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .5
                text: "Ok"
                on_release:
                    root.update(root)
                    root.dismiss()

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .5
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.dismiss()



<Invoice>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 15, 15

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding : 5, 5
            size_hint: .6, None
            pos_hint: {'x': .18,}


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                padding : 5, 5
                spacing: 10, 10
                size: 800, 40
                size_hint: 1, None

                Button:
                    text: "Show"
                    size_hint_x: .05
                    spacing_x: 30
                    on_press:root.abc()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, 1

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: .5, 1
                padding : 0, 15
                spacing: 10, 10
                size: 500, 30

                GridLayout:
                    id: invoices
                    cols: 2
                    #orientation: "horizontal"
                    padding : 5, 0
                    spacing: 10, 0
                    #size: 500, 30
                    size_hint: 1, 1
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

Comment: Can you modify your example code to actually create and use a `test.db`? Very difficult to debug a problem in code that doesn't display the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `Invoice` instance instead of using the existing one.

```
 Invoice().abc()
```

try instead:

```
class EditPopup(Popup):
    mode = StringProperty("")
    label_rec_id = StringProperty("Id")
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?"])
    index = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(EditPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj # will need it later...

    def update(self,obj):
        #cur.execute("UPDATE `item` SET itemName=?, itemCode=? WHERE itemId=?",
                #('Item1', 9999, 11))
        #con.commit()

        self.obj.abc()  # was Invoice().abc()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

You are instanting a second instance of class Invoice by invoking *Invoice().abc()* at method update in class EditPopup.

## Solution

### 1) test.py

Comment off Invoice().abc() at method update in class EditPopup and add *pass*.

```
def update(self, obj):
    #cur.execute("UPDATE `item` SET itemName=?, itemCode=? WHERE itemId=?",
            #('Item1', 9999, 11))
    #con.commit()
    # Invoice().abc()
    pass
```

### 2) test.kv

Add a call to method abc in class EditPopup after call to method update.

```
    Button:
        size_hint_x: .5
        text: "Ok"
        on_release:
            root.update(root)
            app.root.abc()
            root.dismiss()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Clicked Show Button]
[image: Img03 - Before Changes]
[image: Img04 - After Changes]
[image: Img05 - After Update and invoked method abc]